# Являются ли слова однородными членами предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены, определения

Нужна ли запятая после слова "быстроразвивающегося" в предложении:

**Саммит может продемонстрировать экономические возможности республики как быстроразвивающегося динамичного региона.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Саммит может продемонстрировать экономические возможности республики как быстроразвивающегося динамичного региона.**

С первого взгляда кажется, что это однородные отношения, раскрывающие одну тему, то есть почти синонимы. Но настораживает, что **данная фраза с перечислительной интонацией как-то плохо читается.** Поэтому смотрим предложение в поисковике и видим, **что запятую никто не ставит.**

А вот почему? Надо посмотреть значение слова ***динамичный***. В словаре нужной информации нет, но вот тот же поисковик говорит о том, что это скорее **термин** определенного содержания.

**Стабильно-динамичный регион** определяется  как территориально-экономическая система **с определенными особенностями** (основанная на созданном ранее социально-экономическом потенциале со сложной многоотраслевой структурой хозяйственного комплекса, выгодном географическом положении и благоприятном инновационно-инвестиционном климате и т.д.). https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/osobennosti-razvitiya-stabilno-dinamichnyh-regionov

И если это термин, то отношения между прилагательными будут **неоднородными**. Динамический регион — это определение потенциальных возможностей, а быстроразвивающийся — это использование этих возможностей.

Answer (score 1):

**Саммит может продемонстрировать экономические возможности республики как быстроразвивающегося, динамичного региона.**

[**Однородные определения**](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/713-232_odnorodnye_i_neodnorodnye_opredeleniya.html) напрямую связаны с определяемым (главным) словом. Между собой они находятся в отношениях перечисления (т. е. произносятся с перечислительной интонацией и между ними можно поставить союз **и**):
*быстроразвивающегося **и** динамичного региона.*

Кроме того, определения являются однородными, если в условиях контекста между ними создаются синонимические отношения:
[**динамичный**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/44772) — **способный к** движению, **развитию**, видоизменению.
[Способный к развитию — развивающийся — быстроразвивающийся.]

Получается, что определения однородны, поэтому между ними необходима запятая.